# oozie sqoop action having --map-column-java

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am getting error for sqoop action in oozie workflow. When I run the same sqoop command from unix propmt to test it works, but in oozie it fails

Logs..

Sqoop command arguments :
             import
             --connect
             "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:1433;databaseName=INS;username=xxx;password=xxx"
             --query
             "select * from dbo.tu4h3 WHERE CONCAT(substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),1,10),substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),12,19)) >= '`date "+%Y-%m-%d%T" -d "1 days ago"`' and $CONDITIONS"
             -m
             8
             --target-dir
             hdfs://csaa-aap-qa/user/xgkg5red/tu4h3/2015-08-17
             --fields-terminated-by
             \001
             --compression-codec
             snappy
             --split-by
             TIMESTAMP_UPDATED
             --map-column-java
             TIMESTAMP_UPDATED=String;
Launch time = 1439879702947

## Job launch time = 1439879702947 mapreduce.job.tags = oozie-1759ebad3e0fed00730556361c9eb485

> > > Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

1867 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
1900 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4.2.1.5.0-695
1918 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
1940 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Using default fetchSize of 1000
1940 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool  - Beginning code generation
2230 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: select * from dbo.tu4h3 WHERE CONCAT(substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),1,10),substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),12,19)) >= '`date "+%Y-%m-%d%T" -d "1 days ago"`' and  (1 = 0) 
2323 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: select * from dbo.tu4h3 WHERE CONCAT(substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),1,10),substring(convert (CHAR(20),TIMESTAMP_UPDATED,120),12,19)) >= '`date "+%Y-%m-%d%T" -d "1 days ago"`' and  (1 = 0) 
2339 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter  - No ResultSet method for Java type String;
2340 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Imported Failed: No ResultSet method for Java type String;
Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://csaa-aap-qa/user/hdfs/oozie-oozi/0000910-150729052958048-oozie-oozi-W/create-sqoop--sqoop/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with Sqoop or with Java.

Your Sqoop arguments contain a **dynamic parameter** that is expressed as a **bash script snippet**, using `date`. So it works when you run it in a Linux console.

But Oozie is not a Linux console, it's a Java application. The "date" stuff is handled as a string litteral. That's why it shows as-is in the error message - something that you should have noticed.

If you are interested in dynamic date parameters in Oozie, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033005/how-can-i-pass-a-dynamic-date-in-a-hive-server-action-as-a-parameter/).

Comment: Without "--map-column-java TIMESTAMP_UPDATED=String; " this my sqoop action works fine..Timestamp_updated is datetime datatype column in the table nothing is dynamic here....

Comment: Thanks Samson...I moved that date  dynamic parameter to shell action in oozie..now I am able to run it successfully